# No ChallengeStatusReceiver for transaction id

Tags: android, react-native, stripe-payments, 3d-secure

My React Native app is crashing when some users try to add a payment method in production. This is happening on **Android only**. I cannot reproduce it in debug. I'm getting this mysterious error report in Sentry and after some Googling I have no idea what this error means:

`No ChallengeStatusReceiver for transaction id`

```
d.q.a.g1.i.d: No ChallengeStatusReceiver for transaction id 
    at d.q.a.g1.l.s.a
    at d.q.a.g1.l.q.c
    at d.q.a.g1.l.q.b
    at d.q.a.g1.l.y$a.onPostExecute
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:755)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$900(AsyncTask.java:192)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:772)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

I'm using [tipsi-stripe](https://github.com/tipsi/tipsi-stripe) and I'm pretty sure this error is happening when calling `stripe.confirmSetupIntent()`. This method presents an authentication "challenge" if the user's bank requires it.

The flow I'm using now is:

1. user enter payment details:

```
const createPaymentMethodParams = {
  "billingDetails":{
    "name":"First Last"
  },
  "card":{
    "cvc":"333",
    "expMonth":12,
    "expYear":23,
    "number":"4111111111111111"
  }
}
```

2. Call the backend, which creates a setup intent with `confirmation_method=manual`. This returns a `client_secret`
3. "Create" the payment method with `createPaymentMethod`, which returns payment method id.

```
const paymentMethodData = await
    stripe.createPaymentMethod(createPaymentMethodParams)
```

4. Finally, confirm the setup intent (this is the step which sometimes crashes):

```
// confirm the setup intent:
// - if authentication is required user will be redirected to auth flow
// - if no authentication is required this directly returns paymentMethodId
const { status, paymentMethodId } = await stripe.confirmSetupIntent({
  clientSecret: intent.client_secret, // previously obtained from backend
  paymentMethodId: paymentMethodData.id,
})
```

The most relevant result I found on Google was this https://adyen.github.io/adyen-3ds2-android/com/adyen/threeds2/ChallengeStatusReceiver.html
It refers to a 3DS sdk (as in "3-D Secure"), which would make sense to see at this stage when the user is required to authenticate. However I'm really not sure I'm on the right track...

Has anyone encountered this issue and can help me understand it, or point me in a direction? Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you share the integration pattern you're following for using `confirmSetupIntent`? Are you sure what you're doing is supported by `tipsi-stripe`?

Comment: @NolanH Thanks for your reply. I added some more details about the flow. And yes I'm sure SCA/3DSecure flows are supported by tipsi-stripe. I have this working in production for the vast majority of users.